# Should I use many joins inside unions or pull them out using subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, which should be more efficient?

I have a need to do 16 unions and each one joins with the same view.
I need the total from 16 different views which are totaling values from 16 different tables.  I need the data in the following format...
project   category   total

```
1         rentals    $10
1         equipment  $200
2         rentals    $10
2         equipment  $300
```

Should I use subqueries and only have one join at the 'end' or keep the joins within each union?

view_project is a view on a table
view_categoryX is a view which totals line items for the category by project_id.  There are separate tables for each of these (not the best design, but it is out of scope to redesign the table structure).

First option

```
    select view_project.project_name, view_project.num, view_project.fiscal_year,
       view_category1.name, view_category1.total from view_category1 inner join view_project on view_project.project_id = view_category1.project_id 

where view_project.is_open = 1
union all
select view_project.project_name, view_project.num, view_project.fiscal_year,
       view_category2.name, view_category2.total
from view_category2
inner join view_project on view_project.project_id = view_category2.project_id
where view_project.is_open = 1
...
/* This continues on with the same pattern for a total of 16 unions */
```

or second option

```
select view_project.project_name, view_project.num, view_project.fiscal_year,
       view_category_total.name, view_category_total.total
       from view_project
       inner join 
       (
       select category_name, total from view_category1
       union ALL
       select category_name, total from view_category2
       ...
       /* unions continue on for a total of 16 unions */
       ) view_category_total
       On view_project.project_id = view_category_total.project_id
       where view_project.is_open = 1
```

Comment: Questions about performance must include the execution plan of each option.

Comment: *"I have a need to do 16 unions"* This sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to start with. Why do you "need" *16* `UNION`s?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'execution plan'?

Comment: SSMS `Include Actual Execution plan` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16 please upload the XML of the plan to https://pastetheplan.com and share the link

Comment: Execution plan would expose too many inner details  so I cannot share it.

Comment: @user1579692 then we can't help you. Although those "inner details" are almost always far less important than people think. There's no "proprietary information" or "intellectual property" when queries and common techniques are copied from SO and books over the years. You'll have to compare the execution plans yourself. Are they different in the two cases? The query optimizer transforms queries to find the best execution plan so it's quite likely the two queries will produce the same execution plan.

Comment: @user1579692 why are there 16 UNIONs? Did someone try to manually partition tables? All supported versions and editions of SQL Server support table partitioning so there's no reason for manual partitioning. Even SQL Server Express supports this.

Comment: @user1579692 you can put both queries in the same window, enable `Include Actual Execution Plan` and compare their cost. Is one or the other more expensive? Or the same? If those were *tables* they'd probably be the same.

Comment: You can anonymize the plan using SentryOne Plan Explorer. We can't help you without the plan

Comment: It is of course possible to answer some performance questions without seeing a query plan. If I wrote a "select" using a cursor that called a stored procedure to calculate the value of an additional value for each row, wrote each row to a temp table, and then selected from the temp table when the cursor was done, but I could also write the query as a select statement with an inline expression to calculate the additional column, nobody would be asking for the plans. What commenters are saying is that in this case there's not any obvious, generally knowable difference of this kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I built both queries and tested them.
The second one is faster.
I ran the queries on my local dev database, test server, and production server.
Second query was always faster.
The difference on my local database was significant (10x or more faster)
On the Test server it was 50% faster.
On Production it was 13% faster.

So, as the database server became more and more robust the difference was diminished.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CTE for encapsulating UNION section, then join it with other tables. like this SQL Snip code:

```
`WITH main AS (
SELECT view_project.project_name
    ,view_project.num
    ,view_project.fiscal_year
    ,view_category1.name
    ,view_category1.total
    ,project_id
FROM view_category1
UNION
SELECT view_project.project_name
    ,view_project.num
    ,view_project.fiscal_year
    ,view_category2.name
    ,view_category2.total
    ,project_id
FROM view_category2
) SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN view_project ON view_project.project_id = main.project_id WHERE view_project.is_open = 1`
```

Comment: Does this answer the OP's question about performance? Your query is also not logically the same as OP's, they are using `union all`, you are using `union`. This could change the results, and will certainly change the performance

Comment: You may use "UNION ALL" in my query if needed. "UNION" distincts 2 datasets. but "UNION ALL" not.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (IMO): This depends

I kinda learned the hard way: There rarely is such a thing in SQL Server as "reliably predictable performance optimizations". True, there some general guidelines, but in the end: You kinda have to test it out (yeah, I know you did not want to hear that). Alternatively, you would need to provide way more info, as all of that has influence on performance:

- Partitioning
- Indices
- Number of rows
- Types and sizes of included columns
- Available RAM and processor cores
- General load of the server
- Disk size and speed
- Statistics
- All sorts of weird server settings

and probably a lot more that I did not think of atm.
The problem is, SQL Server is not always behaving as it should. For example, if you chain too many sub-queries, CTEs,... performance often crumbles to a halt and can be fixed by storing the sub-results in temporary tables (which btw. is exactly what SQL Server does if you use those sub-queries, CTEs etc.). In the end that has to do with what exact query plan SQL Server generates for you. Or, in the end, my suggestion (that I have been executing for quite a while with a quite good results):

- Learn which possible options (performance-wise) exist that you could use.
- Try it out and measure the results (first with test loads, then with production loads! - production can sometimes yield vastly different results due to usually far better servers, but also way more data and general server load, restrictive load balancers etc.)

As a last note: Since you are doing this on views (which sometimes can confuse the query plan generator as well), there are even more things you may consider, like:

store the results from the union all in a temp table.

or: copy the first table into a new table, then insert the other ones (probably only faster if those views contain really complex queries)

only then join the data from the temp table (or regular table) with view_project. However this also depends on whether that query shall be executable in parallel (like in a stored procedure that can be called by multiple users at the same time) ...

Comment: Yeah, that is what I figured.  Just wanted to check to see if anyone knew offhand which is better.  Truthfully it won't matter too much as the database is relatively small and this will only be run every 2 hrs as it is used to provide data to other systems.